# Ubuntu subversion ANT Build Problems

Tags: ubuntu, ant, svnant

Greetings all I am trying trying to run a simple ant build. I am using ubuntu 12.04. 
I am not sure Why I keep getting an error referencing

> at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter

Can someone take a look at my to help me with this ant build.

my build.xml has.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="AppBuilder" default="war" basedir="..">

    <property name="project.name" value="DIS" />

    <property name="checkout.dir" value="home/mark/Desktop/checkout" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="home/mark/Desktop/build" />
    <property name="server.dir" 
    value="Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/test1/servers/AdminServer/upload"/>

    <property name="repo.url" value="svn://127.0.0.1:3690/eHRMS_Project" />
    <property name="repo.usr" value="mark" />
    <property name="repo.pwd" value="java" />

    <property name="ant.dir" value="apps/apache-ant-1.8.2"/>


<!-- SET THE SVNANT CLASSPATH -->
<path id ="svnant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${ant.dir}/lib/svnant" includes="**/svn*.jar"/>
</path>
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml"
    classpathref="svnant.classpath"/>


<!--REMOVE OLD BUILD -->
<target name="clean">
    <echo>Cleaning directories</echo>
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${checkout.dir}"/>
</target>


<!-- CREATE NEW DIRECTORIES-->
 <target name="init" depends="clean">
    <echo>Creating the directories</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <mkdir dir="${checkout.dir}"/>
</target>


<!--
CHECKOUT THE LATEST CODE FROM THE SVN REPOSITORY.
AN SVN CLIENT MUST BE INSTALLED ON YOUR MACHINE.
-->
<target name="checkoutLatest" depends="init">
  <echo>Checking out the project</echo> 
  <svn  svnkit="false"
    javahl="false"
    username="${repo.usr}" 
    password="${repo.pwd}"> 
      <checkout url="${repo.url}/${project.name}" destPath="${checkout.dir}"/> 
  </svn>
</target>


<!--COMPILE THE JAVA CLASSES-->
<target name="compile" depends="checkoutLatest">
    <echo>Compile the source files</echo>

<javac  srcdir="${checkout.dir}/src"
    destdir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"
    includeAntRuntime="no">

    <!--ALL THE POSSIBLE LOCATIONS OF FILES NEEDED FOR COMPILATION-->        
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="home/mark/Oracle/Middleware/modules">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="home/mark/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </classpath>

</javac>

</target>


<!--TRANSFER WEBCONTENT AND CONFIG FILES FROM CHECKOUT FOLDER TO BUILD FOLDER-->
<target name="copy" depends="compile">
    <echo>Transferring WebContent and config files</echo>

    <!--COPY THE CONFIG/RESOURCE FILES-->
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}/src" excludes="com/**"/>
    </copy>

    <!--COPY THE HBM FILES FOR EHRMS-->
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/com/multivision/ehrms/business">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}/src/com/multivision/ehrms/business" excludes="*.java"/>
    </copy>

    <!--COPY THE HBM FILES FOR DIS-->
    <copy todir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes/com/multivision/dis/businesses">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}/src/com/multivision/dis/businesses" excludes="*.java"/>
    </copy>

    <!--COPY THE WEBCONTENT FILES AND SUBDIRECTORIES-->
    <copy todir="${build.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${checkout.dir}/WebContent"/>
    </copy>

</target>

<!-- CREATE THE WAR-->
<target name="war" depends="copy">
    <echo>Building WAR file</echo>
    <war destfile="${server.dir}/${project.name}.war" 
        webxml="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <fileset dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </war>
</target>
```

My console displays this when I run my ant build

```
 BUILD FAILED
    /home/mark/Desktop/build.xml:52: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: notifylisteners
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.CmdLineNotificationHandler.logException(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.CommandLine.execString(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.SvnCommandLine.checkout(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.commandline.CmdLineClientAdapter.checkout(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.Checkout.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
        at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at     org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

    Total time: 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of svnclientadapter used when compiling svnant is different to the version used in  `svn.classpath`.  Since you haven't stated which version of svnant you're using, it's impossible to tell you the correct version.

When you find out what it is, change the appropriate JAR in `{ant.dir}/lib/svn`

Comment: I am using                                                  `mark@mark-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~$ ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
`

Comment: I have mark@mark-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:~$ `svn --version
svn, version 1.7.6 (r1370777)`
   compiled Aug 21 2012, 14:06:38

Comment: svnant is a subversion extension for ANT. There are several versions available. See: http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.htm

Comment: `svnant` are svn bindings for ant.  There will probably be an `svnant` JAR in `{ant.dir}/lib/svn`

Comment: I do see  svnant.jar in `{ant.dir}/lib/svn` do I have to update it or something

Comment: Yes, read the answer.  You need to make sure the version of `svnclientadapter` is compatible with the version of `svnant` you're using .